# Which English speech sounds are difficult for speakers of Jamaican Patois? What aspects of English grammar may be difficult?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, british-english

I'll soon be supporting a speaker of Jamaican Patois with her spoken and written English. (I'm in the UK)

I understand that the sounds /θ/ and /ð/ are not used in Jamaican Patois, but would like to know if there are any other sounds that may be difficult?

Also, what aspects of English grammar are likely to be tricky for her?  Can you recommend any useful resources to support her learning?

If anyone can throw any light on these questions, I'd be very grateful, as I'd like to be as helpful to her as possible.  Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But do keep coming back. Although we try to follow the site rules and that sometimes makes us seem over-fussy, there are a lot of people here who like to help.

Comment: An interesting teaching situation. How old is the learner (the situation of a four year old is very different from a forty-year-old)  To what extent is she capable of diglossia Many patois speakers will code-switch between patois and "English with a Jamaican accent" as social context requires) And if she can code-switch, then there is a question about how far you should try to change her accent.

Comment: "11.1.21" is ambiguous, although given the future construction ("I'm going to"), you probably mean November rather than January.